# E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. installing nvidia-driver 535

Tags: apt, nvidia, gpu-driver

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535
```

````
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-535 : Depends: libnvidia-compute-535 (= 535.104.12-0ubuntu1) but 535.113.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.3 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-extra-535 (= 535.104.12-0ubuntu1) but 535.113.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.3 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-decode-535 (= 535.104.12-0ubuntu1) but 535.113.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.3 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-535 (= 535.104.12-0ubuntu1) but 535.113.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.3 is to be installed
                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535 (= 535.104.12-0ubuntu1) but 535.113.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.3 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-535 (= 535.104.12-0ubuntu1) but 535.113.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.3 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-535 (= 535.104.12-0ubuntu1) but 535.113.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.3 is to be installed
                     Recommends: nvidia-settings but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: nvidia-prime (>= 0.8) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-compute-535:i386 (= 535.104.12-0ubuntu1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-535:i386 (= 535.104.12-0ubuntu1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-535:i386 (= 535.104.12-0ubuntu1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-535:i386 (= 535.104.12-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 1):

Before the update, you need to clear old nvidia file from your system, which requires a reboot. Then, force-install the packages needed. Finally, install the driver as intended.

*Run these with `sudo`,* not *as root!*

##### 1. Purge nvidia-*

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
sudo apt update
sudo reboot
```

##### 2. Force install dependencies and fix

```
sudo apt install -y libnvidia-fbc1-535 libnvidia-cfg1-535 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535 libnvidia-encode-535 libnvidia-decode-535 libnvidia-extra-535 libnvidia-compute-535
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

##### 3. Install driver

```
sudo apt install -y nvidia-driver-535
```

Reboot one last time, and you should be golden.

Comment: Tell me if it helped

Comment: Not worked! same error

Comment: Worked for me, with a little more to do. Start with `apt purge nvidia-*` and reboot. Then, as the last step you can install the driver and reboot one last time.

Comment: Does not work. By the way, the Linux kernel version is `6.5.4-76060504-generic`. Has anyone successfully installed CUDA for this version? After the kernel update, my CUDA is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You first must purge existing nvidia driver.
lets say you have `nvidia-driver-470`

1. Run `sudo apt purge nvidia-driver-470`. You also need to purge all nvidia stuff related to that driver `470`
2. Install `dkms` using `apt`
3. Run `sudo apt update`
4. Restart your PC
5. Run `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535`

Ask me more if you still have any problems!

Comment: This is a good first step, and will probably solve the problem for anyone who hasn't already messed up their cache trying other solutions. Didn't work for me though.

Answer (score 0):

Improving @noone answer above, this worked for me:

1. Purge nvidia-*

   ```
   sudo apt purge nvidia-*
   sudo apt update
   sudo reboot
   ```
2. Install the exact required version:

   ```
   sudo apt libnvidia-compute-535=535.104.12-0ubuntu1
   ```
3. Force install dependencies and fix

   ```
   sudo apt install -y libnvidia-fbc1-535 libnvidia-cfg1-535 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535 libnvidia-encode-535 libnvidia-decode-535 libnvidia-extra-535 libnvidia-compute-535
   sudo apt --fix-broken install
   ```
4. Install driver

   ```
   sudo apt install -y nvidia-driver-535
   ```

Edit:
If the error persists due to dependencies keep installing the specific versions for each package until you have success. gdebi will list them on by one, always printing the first unmet dependency. apt will print all, so you have to be carefull to install all of the dependencies (almost 10).